# Blazor unit testing with browser restrictions

Tags: blazor, bunit

When running a Blazor app in the browser, many .NET methods will throw a `PlatformNotSupportedException`, for example, `TcpClient.ConnectAsync()`. This is fine, but I want to run unit tests that will catch these types of restrictions.

I have found that when running bUnit tests (within a default bUnit project), that executing `TcpClient.ConnectAsync()` *does not* throw an exception. This is not what I want; I don't want to be developing services that may call APIs that will pass at test-time but fail at run-time.

How can I run unit tests that intentionally have the same restrictions that would exist in an app running in the browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bUnit is platform agnostic. You can use it to test components that are used by Blazor Server, Wasm, Maui or some other runtime.

So, in the context of a bUnit test, it may not make sense to test for such things.

In general, according to this, you cannot override the platform you are running under: [How to run specific unit tests only when running on a specific operating system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69043074/how-to-run-specific-unit-tests-only-when-running-on-a-specific-operating-system), so your best bet is to perform smoke tests with e.g. Playwrite instead.